# parse the official language from 'infobox geography vcard' in wikipedia

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the official language from a series of country in my csv file.

I'm parsing the page with python and BeautifulSoup to get the data from wikipedia (e.g. `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + placeName`). Some of the pages have `class = 'infobox geography vcard'` as their table. I try to extract with the following code but they all print out 'Table is null' (even in pages with the DOM like Albania, Andorra etc...).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
with open('district.csv', 'r') as csv_file2:
    csv_reader2 = csv.reader(csv_file2)       
    for line in csv_reader2:
    url3 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + str(line)
    hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r1 = requests.get(url3, hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find(class_='infobox geography vcard')
    result = {}
    if table is not None:
        for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
            if tr.find('td'):
                result=tr.find('td').text
            else:
                result = str(line) + "is Null"
    else:
        result = "Table is Null"
    print(str(line) + result)
```

Comment: Try disable javascript in your browser and inspect site. Content can be changed by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this only on the Albania website, so check to see if it works for the others, but in the case of Albania, this loop:

```
for i in soup.find_all('th'):
   if 'Official' in i.text:
       print(i.text+':',i.find_parent().find('a').text)
```

Outputs:

> Official languages: Albanian